# Pocketsoap TcpTrace does not show response data

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, tcptrace-pocketsoap, tcptrace

I have a web service with endpoint:

```
 <endpoint address="http://localhost:7002/GeoMat.asmx" binding="basicHttpBinding"
 bindingConfiguration="Geometrik HesaplamalarSoap" contract="GeoMatService.GeometrikHesaplamalarSoap"
 name="Geometrik HesaplamalarSoap"/>
```

When I trace soap I can see request data but can't see response data. 
In red rectangular you can see requests but in the second part instead of response there is a small icon.
How can I fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message is being shown. You can see all the headers the WebService is sending, and then a blank line. The final line is the body of the response; it looks like it contains binary data. TcpTrace is not going to do anything with that save shove the bits at the screen.

TcpTrace was I believe written to trace text messages: it expects the body to be text like HTML. When used against something which sends back binary data, it has no idea what to do with it. How could it?